# ReactJS made big file size after productions. Why is that?

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, code-splitting

I am making a react app and I am having an issue of big file sizes while production build version of React app. Let me tell you a bit more about my react app. It's an HTML template builder app. Users add different sections to create full page template. The problem is that I have a lot of React Class-based component files, its almost 2.5k files. And I am calling those components by the react-loadable library. It's working fine with production and development mode. But the main problem is that when I built that process for production the size has been gone to 65mb more or less. How can I optimisation the size of the production app.js file?

I am attaching some snapshots of my code.

**I am using [loadable component](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components) library for splitting the code**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Loadable from "react-loadable";
import AddSection from "./addSection";
import EditorContext from "../context/index";
import { Button, Icon } from "antd";
import SectionMenu from "./section_menu";

class Content extends Component {
  static contextType = EditorContext;
  // this.data = ["page1/section_0", "page1/section_1"] // its all react file in an array

  handleLib = val => {
    const { setLibraryModal, project } = this.context;

    let index = project.data.findIndex(p => p.id === val.id);

    setLibraryModal(true, index);
  };
  render() {
    const data = this.context.project.data;
    const { loading } = this.context;
    return (<div className="cwp_content_area">
        {data && data.map((val, ind) => {
            const LoadableComponent = Loadable({
              loader: () => import(`../../../divi-pages/${val.data}`),
              loading: () => <h1>Loading</h1>
            });
            return loading ? (
              <h1>Loading</h1>
            ) : (
              <div className="cwp_section" key={ind}>
                <SectionMenu value={val} />
                <LoadableComponent />
                <Button
                  onClick={() => this.handleLib(val)}
                  className="add_section_middle"
                  type="primary"
                >
                  <Icon type="plus" />
                </Button>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        <AddSection />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Content;
```

**The following list files size built up after productions**
[image]

It's really painful to load 65mb for user end. I want to compress the file size then I can go with live project. Can anyone help with that or give me another and best approach.

Comment: [Please don't add code as screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Ok, let me update the post with code.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28098487/7470360

Comment: I already tried this hook in Webpack. But it doesn't much compress the files. I don't know it doesn't omit the separate chunk files while productions. Its merged all chunk files into one or two JS files.